# Onedrive multipart upload

Tags: node.js, onedrive

I am trying to perform multipart upload on OneDrive. Executing following code:

```
function multipartUpload() {
    var boundary = '-------48492abalalal22200';
    var delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    var close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

    var metadata = prepMetadata()

    metadata['@microsoft.graph.sourceUrl'] = 'cid:content'
    metadata.name = saveTo.fileName
    metadata.file = {}

    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-ID: <metadata>\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-ID: <content>\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        '\r\n'

    uploadReq.once('res', function(res, body) {
        if(res.statusCode != 200)
            return self.emit('res', {
                code: res.statusCode,
                message: res.statusMessage
            })

        var metadata = parse(body)

        if(metadata.error)
            return self.emit('res', metadata.error);

        self.emit('res', null, {
            doneWithFile: true
        });
    })

    if(saveTo.parentID == '/')
        var item = '/root/children'
    else
        var item = '/items/' + saveTo.parentID + '/children'

    self.writable = uploadReq.issue({
        options: {
            hostname: hostname,
            path: basePath + item,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary=' + boundary
            }
        }
    });

    self.writable.write(multipartRequestBody)

    var endUpload = self.writable.end.bind(self.writable)

    self.writable.end = function() {
        endUpload(close_delim)
    }
}
```

I am writing body self.writable somewhere else.

What I understand is that whatever metadata is provided it will be added to children collection. But Here is the ERROR:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.",
            "innerError": {
                "request-id": "c98da348f31-325659b2d76d",
                    "date": "2017-04-17T15:25:51"
            }
    }
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Please help.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong... I believe Graph doesn't actually support multipart even though OneDrive Consumer does.

Comment: I agree with you there is no documentation of multipart file upload in https://graph.microsoft.io/ documentation. But there is for https://dev.onedrive.com/